# Is there a way to make the image gallery/carousel go to the other side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery

I am trying to set up an image gallery/carousel (https://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-a-jquery-image-scroller/), where one line runs from right to left and the next one from left to right. 
It should look something like a newsticker (see: https://www.welt.de/newsticker/) just with photos.

I found some code to set up the image gallery/carousel from left to right, but I can't seem to figure out how I can make it move the other way. Does anyone have an idea?

Already tried to work with the html tag marquee but that seems to be not a good practice as the tag isn't recommended any longer. Also tried to work with CSS but then again, I learned (I'm very new to coding) that any effects/moving etc. should be programmed with js.

I wish to have the gallery running the other way.

```js
$(function() {
  var scroller = $('#scroller div.innerScrollArea');
  var scrollerContent = scroller.children('ul');
  scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);
  var curX = 0;
  scrollerContent.children().each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('left', curX);
    curX += $this.outerWidth(true);
  });
  var fullW = curX / 2;
  var viewportW = scroller.width();

  // Scrolling speed management
  var controller = {
    curSpeed: 0,
    fullSpeed: 2
  };
  var $controller = $(controller);
  var tweenToNewSpeed = function(newSpeed, duration) {
    if (duration === undefined)
      duration = 600;
    $controller.stop(true).animate({
      curSpeed: newSpeed
    }, duration);
  };

  // Pause on hover
  scroller.hover(function() {
    tweenToNewSpeed(0);
  }, function() {
    tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
  });

  // Scrolling management; start the automatical scrolling
  var doScroll = function() {
    var curX = scroller.scrollLeft();
    var newX = curX + controller.curSpeed;
    if (newX > fullW * 2 - viewportW)
      newX -= fullW;
    scroller.scrollLeft(newX);
  };
  setInterval(doScroll, 20);
  tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
});
```

```css
#scroller {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#scroller .innerScrollArea {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#scroller ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#scroller li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroller" class="marquee">
  <div class="innerScrollArea">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="coffee.jpg" width="600" height="400" /></li>
      <li><img src="containerworker.jpg" width="600" height="400" /></li>
      <li><img src="coffee.jpg" width="600" height="400" /></li>
      <li><img src="containerworker.jpg" width="600" height="400" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scroll right, you should change `fullSpeed` to `-2` & add condition to reset `newX` when it overflows.

```js
$(function() {
  var scroller = $('#scroller div.innerScrollArea');
  var scrollerContent = scroller.children('ul');
  scrollerContent.children().clone().appendTo(scrollerContent);
  var curX = 0;
  scrollerContent.children().each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('left', curX);
    curX += $this.outerWidth(true);
  });
  var fullW = curX / 2;
  var viewportW = scroller.width();

  // Scrolling speed management
  var controller = {
    curSpeed: 0,
    fullSpeed: -2
  };
  var $controller = $(controller);
  var tweenToNewSpeed = function(newSpeed, duration) {
    if (duration === undefined)
      duration = 600;
    $controller.stop(true).animate({
      curSpeed: newSpeed
    }, duration);
  };

  // Pause on hover
  scroller.hover(function() {
    tweenToNewSpeed(0);
  }, function() {
    tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
  });

  // Scrolling management; start the automatical scrolling
  var doScroll = function() {
    var curX = scroller.scrollLeft();
    var newX = curX + controller.curSpeed;
    if (newX < fullW) {
      newX = fullW * 2 - viewportW;
    }
    if (newX > fullW * 2 - viewportW)
      newX -= fullW;
    scroller.scrollLeft(newX);
  };
  setInterval(doScroll, 20);
  tweenToNewSpeed(controller.fullSpeed);
});
```

```css
#scroller {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#scroller .innerScrollArea {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#scroller ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#scroller li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroller" class="marquee">
  <div class="innerScrollArea">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="coffee.jpg" width="600" height="400" /></li>
      <li><img src="containerworker.jpg" width="600" height="400" /></li>
      <li><img src="coffee.jpg" width="600" height="400" /></li>
      <li><img src="containerworker.jpg" width="600" height="400" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```